# Set Value Dynamically Based on Column Header and Intersection of Target Row

Tags: vba, dynamic, offset

the people on this site have been so helpful and I hope someone can help me figure out how to use dynamic column headers to assign a value in my code.  I have a sub set up as a Before Double Click Target, with all the targets in column A.  Right now I have it working fine, assigning values using the offset method.  I need to pull data from cells in the target row and so long as the columns do not get moved, it is great. However, users are now adding columns but the headers of the columns I need will not be changed.  I need to now change this to a dynamic lookup based on the intersection of the target row and a specific column based on their headers.  I can set values that find the columns I want, but have not been able to get the data to pull correctly based on the target row.  I thought that the Intersect property would work but it does not seem to, as that is based on finding the target itself within a range.  I need to find a cell relative to the target, intersecting with the column based on a header.  That value will be used elsewhere in the sub.  What step am I missing?

This segment of the code is below, and you can see I have a hybrid right now, some with the straight up offsets based on column numbers, then the other where I am trying to use assigned column names nameCol and nameCol1.  The offset method works, but when I try to use the headers to define where to look on the target row, it does not work.  Thank you.

```
Set nameCol = Range("A1:Z1").Find("Last")
Set nameCol1 = Range("A1:Z1").Find("First")
Set nameCol2 = Range("A1:Z1").Find("Name")
Set nameCol3 = Range("A1:Z1").Find("Date")


 'Check active column is column 1 (Where you want the macro to be called from)
  If Target.Column = 1 Then
    With Target
        sName = .Value
        sAction = .Offset(0, 24).Value + 365
        Set foundCell = .Offset(0, nameCol.Column)
        Set foundcell1 = .Offset(0, nameCol1.Column)
        Set foundcell3 = .Offset(0, 36)
        Set foundcell4 = .Offset(0, 35)
        sReason = .Offset(0, 6).Value
        foundcell2 = .Offset(0, 6)
```

Comment: Set FoundCell = Cells(Target.Row,namecol.Column)

Comment: Holy crap, what a quick reply, and it was perfect!!!  Scott, thank you so much!  Honestly, I sit here all day trying to figure this stuff out on my own.  Then I post here and get an answer that fixes everything in minutes!  You guys rock!  I did try the .row property earlier but at the time I had not defined my name columns.  So I kept getting errors.  Now, with your code it worked a treat, cheers!  Scott, can you please post your reply as an answer so I can mark it as answered and you get the credit?

Comment: `sAction = .Offset(0, 24).Value + 365` trying to add a year to a date? Check this [DateAdd](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/dateadd-function) function.

Comment: Hey, thanks Patrick, I am going to try that out!  More knowledge, I love this site!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was the answer, given by the below:
Set FoundCell = Cells(Target.Row,namecol.Column) --Scott Craner